# Вопрос по выводу

Tags: c#

> В этом задании необходимо написать программу, объявит две переменные: первая переменная - переменная целочисленного (int) типа со значением 99, вторая переменная - переменная действительного (double) типа со значением 0.3525. Перемножьте эти две переменные и результат выполнения назначьте двум новым переменным: целочисленного и вещественного типа. Выведите эти две последние переменные отдельно в новой строке в следующем порядке: целочисленная переменная, действительно переменная (каждое значение должно быть написано в новой строке без знаков препинания).

Код написал:

```
using System;

public class Test
{
    private static double result;
    private static int res;

    public static void Main()
    {

        double b = 0.3525, y;
        int a = 99, x;
        y = a * b;
        x = (int)y;
        result = y;
        res = x;

        System.Console.WriteLine(result);
        System.Console.WriteLine(res);

    }
}
```

Но не могу конкретно понять, что в нём я не так сделал, как написано в задании? 
Извиняюсь за такие глупые вопросы, просто решил поучить прогу, но тут немного столкнулся с непониманием.

Comment: Ой, я извиняюсь.

Comment: Вам по сути не нужны поля `result` и `res`, достаточно локальных переменных `x`, `y`.

Comment: Спасибо, учту =)

Answer (score 1):

Сначала просят вывести int, потом double. У вас наоборот.

Answer (score 1):

Собственно, работает верно. Могу дать небольшое замечание по коду. Вот это читается сложно, лучше разделять.

```
double b = 0.3525, y;
int a = 99, x;
```

Заменить на

```
int a = 99;
double b = 0.3525;
double y = a * b; // Здесь приведение int a в double произойдет автоматически.
int x = (int) y; // Здесть приведение результата double в int необходимо делать вручную. Результат округлиться.
```

Ну и выводим результат в одной строке:

```
Console.WriteLine(x);
Console.WriteLine(y);
```

Comment: Подправил, прочитал криво.

Comment: Спасибо большое!
Это было верное решение :)

Answer (score 0):

И еще похоже, что вывести нужно на одной строке.

```
System.Console.WriteLine(res + " " + result);
```

Comment: «каждое значение должно быть написано в новой строке без знаков препинания»

Comment: В задании указано "...каждое значение должно быть написано в новой строке..."